# Is there a way to use --link and --net=host on Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am making a Node Reverse Proxy system and all works 100% when I don't have it on Docker, but when I do put it on Docker, I am unable to access services that aren't running in the same docker container.

Currently, my setup is 1x Redis Container, 1x MongoDB container, and 1x Proxy Container (linked together w/ --link homerouter-redis --link homerouter-mongo). Just like that, it all works as expected, wahoo! Except, when I try and reverse proxy a service that is not running inside the Docker, such as on port :8080, I am unable to connect. So, after a bit of research, I found --net=host, however that made it so I couldn't use my Redis and Mongo container as it would say connection refused.

I've searched for a while and cannot seem to find a solution to this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Docker Compose (unused in this scenario, but still)

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: homerouter-mongo
    image: 'mongo:4'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  redis:
    container_name: homerouter-redis
    image: 'redis:5'
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - 6376:6379
  homerouter:
    privileged: true
    container_name: homerouter
    restart: on-failure
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - redis
      - mongo
    depends_on: 
      - redis
      - mongo
    command: npm start
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/homerouter

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]

EXPOSE 80
```

(also, a completely off-topic question, is Docker Compose production ready?)

Comment: If possible can you make network as host for all the three containers., that will solve the problem, no need of --link.

Comment: @mchawre thanks for the idea! I just tried it, but when I did, MongoDB couldn't connect (and I'd assume Redis either, it didn't get that far), it through the error: `MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [homerouter-mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND homerouter-mongo homerouter-mongo:27017]`... any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: the connection string when you use network as host should be `host-ip:port` not `homerouter-mongo::port`. Change `homerouter-mongo` to the ip of machine.

Comment: @mchawre oh alright, it works perfectly now :D However, is it still worth it to dockerize Mongo and Redis? What are the pros now of running it in-container vs on-host? Scalability? Sorry for the beginner questions, still learning this

Comment: This is a broader question please go through few of these resources https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/what-are-the-reasons-docker-should-not-be-used-for-databases/3374 https://vsupalov.com/database-in-docker/ https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/amo2cc/running_production_databases_in_docker/

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**
All that I needed to do was add --net=host to all of them and no longer use the container name when connecting (instead, I used 127.0.0.1)